# CSS and jQuery Selector Speed

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

In jQuery whenever I encounter something like this:

```
$("div#MyDiv").....
```

I generally say to the developer: "Don't bother putting the `div` in front of `#MyDiv`, ID selectors are the fastest." I.e.

```
$("#MyDiv")....
```

This is because the latter will hook directly into `document.getElementById` rather than having to scan the DOM for all `<div>` elements first.

My question is, do the same rules apply to CSS selectors? I.e. rather than:

```
div#MyDiv
{
}
```

Is it faster to have simply?:

```
#MyDiv
{
}
```

(I realise that CSS selectors are incredibly fast anyway, so in reality neither would make a significant difference.)

Many Thanks

**EDIT**

Any links, or references might be useful for the purposes of this discussion.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Consider the case of:  $("...<img id='foo'/>...").find("#foo"). Ouch. Suddenly the assertions went through the roof (I am unaware how this case actually would work though.) Anyway, *the two CSS rules above have different precedence* (the form qualified with the tag being just ever so slightly higher).

Comment: @pst - Not sure I follow. Can you expand?

Comment: Consider the case where the elements are not attached to the document yet. (How *does* jQuery handle this? Not related to the final question though.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say that it's ***extremely unlikely*** that it makes any real-world difference. In theory, yes, there's one fewer check required (because `div#foo` really does need to be a `div` to match the selector, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#id-selectors)). But the odds of it making any real difference in a real-world browser app? Near zero.

That said, I *always* cringe when I see things like `div#foo` in HTML applications. HTML has only one ID-type attribute (`id`), so there's no need for the further qualification. You make the CSS selector engine (either the browser's or jQuery's) work harder to figure out what you mean, you make the selector fragile (if the `div` becomes a `footer`, for instance), etc., and of course you *do* leave yourself open to a stoopid selector implementation that fails to recognize that it can look something up by ID and *then* check to see if it's a `div` and so goes looking through all the `div`s. (Does such an implementation exist? Possibly, you never know.) Barring some edge cases, it always makes me think someone doesn't quite know what they're doing.

So for me, speed isn't the main argument. Pointlessness is. ;-)

Comment: Well, you *could* have a page with a `p#foo` and *another* page with a `div#foo`, both pages including the same Javascript, and you only want the script to apply to the `div#foo`... Not that that's a sane script or markup, but just saying... ;o)

Comment: @deceze: Absolutely, that would be one of the edge cases I was talking about. (Another being if you wanted to allow advanced HTML-enabled user content on the page, and style it differently depending on whether it was a `div` or a `span`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

yes this is faster because of parsing speed and because browser must not check if element is also a `<div>`. (for a few rules speed difference is not perceivable by the user)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/writing_efficient_css#Don.e2.80.99t_qualify_ID_Rules_with_tag_names_or_classes), it does make a difference, although a minute one. (Note that while that article discusses styling XUL user interfaces, the Gecko layout engine is used *both* for rendering Firefox's user interface and the Web pages it loads.)

The ID is meant to apply to a single element in the DOM anyway, so the performance hit incurred by attempting to match the tag name is completely unnecessary, whether significant or not. Not to mention it would waste a few bytes in your stylesheet as well.

Comment: The article doesn't back it up with any data, though.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yeah, unfortunately. That's as much as I can find for now.